# Difference between using "set" and not using set for variables? In Cygwin.

Tags: variables, cygwin, environment-variables

I don’t understand the difference between:

```
set youtube=’https://youtube.com’
```

and

```
youtube=’https://youtube.com’
```

With the second one, I’m able to use it in the middle of a command, such as:

```
cygstart $youtube
```

and that works.

Why and how are these different?    They both set variables?
And, when I don't use the word "set" I have to expand the variable using $?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two commands are completely unrelated; `set youtube='https://youtube.com'` has nothing to do with `$youtube`. What it does is, it sets `$1` to the whole string `'youtube=https://youtube.com'`.

Per http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin, `set` is a shell builtin with three distinct purposes:

1. If you don't give it any options or arguments, it prints out all the existing shell variables and functions.
2. It has various options that let you change various properties of the shell. For example, `set -C` tells the shell that you don't want `>` to overwrite existing files (and that you instead want commands to fail if they would otherwise do that); and `set +C` tells the shell that never mind, you now want `>` to be able to overwrite files again.
3. Any arguments, other than options, replace the positional parameters (`$1` and `$2` and so on, as well as `$@` and `$*`).

Since `set youtube='https://youtube.com'` calls `set` with exactly one argument, namely `youtube=https://youtube.com`, it has the effect of setting the first positional parameter (`$1`) to `youtube=https://youtube.com`.

Note that `youtube='https://youtube.com'` is a somewhat misleading way to write `youtube=https://youtube.com`; the single-quotes aren't doing anything here (since the sole purpose of single-quotes is to escape whitespace and special characters, and `https://youtube.com` doesn't have any of these).

Comment: Even after reading the  link you suggested, I'm still confused.  Sorry for noobing.  Obviously, I understand that they're different, that's why I asked the question.  But it isn't clear to me what the keyword "set" is doing here.  thanks.

Comment: @Hunle: And my point wasn't "they're different"; my point was "they're so completely unrelated that it's meaningless to ask what the difference between them is". (Imagine that someone posted a question saying, "I don't understand the difference between `foo=bar` and `foo bar`. With the latter, it successfully runs my program `foo`, but with the former, it doesn't. What is the `=` operator doing?" It's a reasonable question, but tricky to answer, because the behavior of `foo bar` is completely irrelevant to a question about `foo=bar`.)